# Java LinkedList accessing 2nd element

Tags: java, linked-list

I have created a linkedlist which stores two elements. Can someone tell me how to access the second element. In this case, the `lastName`

This is what I came up with so far.

```
public class Bank
{
  private LinkedList<List> words = new LinkedList<List>();
  public void startup()
   {
     words.add(new List("Fred","Cool"));
   }
```

This is my list class

```
public class List
{
   public List(String name, String lastName)
   {
     this.name = name;
     this.lastName = lastName;
 }
```

Comment: Hey. Your `List` class is broken. FYI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a number of problems in your code:

1. I suggest you rename your `List` class to `Person`, as object of that type clearly does not represent lists.
2. `name` and `lastName` will not be elements of the list. They are arguments to the constructor of the `List` (read `Person`) class.
3. You have no fields in your `List`, so you can't do

   ```
   this.name = name;
   this.lastName = lastName;
   ```

To access the second element in the `words` list, you do

```
words.get(1);   // access second element (indecies are 0-based)
```

However, since you've only **added one element** you won't be able to use the above expression.

---

Here's a complete example to get you on the right track:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

class Bank {
    private LinkedList<Person> persons = new LinkedList<Person>();

    public void startup() {
        persons.add(new Person("Fred", "Cool"));
    }

    public LinkedList<Person> getPersonList() {
        return persons;
    }
}

class Person {
    String name, lastName;

    public Person(String name, String lastName) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bank bank = new Bank();
        bank.startup();

        String lastNameOfFirstPerson = bank.getPersonList().get(0).lastName;
        System.out.println(lastNameOfFirstPerson); // prints "Cool"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
words.get(index).lastName;
```

This is assuming that the field is accessable.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing  linked list element by index can be very inefficient. Try using [`ListIterator<E> LinkedList#listIterator()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#listIterator%28int%29)